# Not getting error traces in wavefront after migrating to spring boot 3

Tags: micrometer-tracing

I was using Spring boot 2 and sleuth dependency to send data to the wavefront. Everything was working but then I migrate spring boot to 3 I changed dependencies, properties like micrometer instead of sleuth. I am getting all 200 result traces but not the error one.

build.grale:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    ...
    ...
    }
    dependencyManagement {
    imports {
    mavenBom "com.wavefront:wavefront-spring-boot-bom:3.0.1"
    }
    }
    dependencies {
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-wavefront'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-reporter-wavefront'
    ...
    ...
    }
```

Application.properties:

```
management.wavefront.source=test-project-server
    management.wavefront.uri=proxy:...
    management.wavefront.application.service-name=test-project-service
    management.wavefront.application.name=test-projectmanagement.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
    management.tracing.enabled=true
```